# Robocopy cannot access the destination on a client pc

Tags: windows, robocopy

Oggetto: robocopy cannot access the destination

Hi over there,
I am having a problem by tyring to execute `robocopy`, to copy a folder hosted on a server (Windows 2008 R2 Server) into a client pc (Windows7) on a LAN.

I try to explain me as better as I can:

- folder name: `test`
- server address: 192.168.**10**.2
- client pc: 192.168.**10**.113
- folder location on the server: `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test`
- pc destination for the folder: `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`

I have executed the following `robocopy` commands:

```
robocopy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test" "\\192.168.10.113\Users\Public\Desktop"

robocopy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test" "\\192.168.10.113\c$\Users\Public\Desktop"

robocopy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test" "\\192.168.10.113\c\Users\Public\Desktop"

robocopy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test" "\\192.168.10.113\c:\Users\Public\Desktop"
```

and I got always the same error message (in italian language):

> Error during access: user name unknown or invalid password

Note: I have disabled Windows firewall on the client.

I've read some articles on the Internet, describing a problem about the configuraiton of a Windows file (`Machine.config`).

I do not know how to go on; can anyone help me?

I do thank you, really, in advance.

ps: I am reading a great file at the following link about Robocopy (just to tell you that I am not sleeping while waiting for an answer). Here is the link: 
[ss64 robocopy syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have administrative rights to run this command.

You're trying to access to a private folder of this server.

Create a new folder, set the correct permissions, and move all content there.

Comment: you must disable firewall in the server too, or allow file sharing